# Using FFPMEG, create a MJPEG stream from a file to simulate a webcam

Tags: ffmpeg, streaming, video-encoding, mjpeg

I'd like to use ffmpeg to simulate a network webcam.
These usually give out an MJPEG feed that plays in a browser.
I want to create a stream like this locally as a test case
for a software I plan to write.

This is the input file

```
Input #1, matroska,webm, from 'webcam.mkv':
  Metadata:
    ENCODER         : Lavf58.29.100
  Duration: 00:27:16.70, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 2664 kb/s
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p(tv, bt709, progressive), 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1k tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      DURATION        : 00:27:16.700000000
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp (default)
    Metadata:
      title           : simple_aac
      DURATION        : 00:27:16.565000000
```

I need a video only MJPEG stream, no audio.

I tried:

```
ffmpeg -i webcam.mkv -vcodec mjpeg -an http://localhost:8090/monitoring1.ffm
```

and get

```
[NULL @ 000001f915d10d80] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'http://localhost:8090/monitoring1.ffm'
http://localhost:8090/monitoring1.ffm: Invalid argument
```

Any way I can select the output format?

Comment: Can you try `-f mjpeg` or similar before `http....` ?

Comment: @Rajib - If I try that, I get `Connection to tcp://localhost:8090 failed: Error number -138 occurred http://localhost:8090/monitoring1.ffm: Unknown error` after a second or two

Comment: This seems to be a tcp/ip port configuration issue. Perhaps you should add that in your tags and edit your question to reflect the new error.

Comment: @Rajib - in this situation, ffmpeg should behave as a server and not connect to anything. A browser would be a client to connect to the localhost address. Anyway, thanks for trying to help.